# Is possible to use .class files that are not in the build?

Tags: java

I wanted to add a system of adding more "commands" to my program from out side of it.

Basically, a folder that would be in the same directory as my jar (executable) that can have a varying number of "extensions"

Each "extension" would be a .class file that extends a certain abstract class that has methods defined for identification, etc.

However, I can't seem to find out if it's even possible to control these `.class` files from outside my main package.

Is this possible? If so how? And if not is there an alternative I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: There are: custom classloaders, OSGi, etc etc. Solutions are many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you. You want to build a plugin system.
If so you should think about the java service provider approach.

In this approach you define a service provider interface (SPI) in your main
package and use the java META-INF/services location to lookup implementations.
In this case you can add extensions just by putting a jar file on the classpath.

As of java 1.6 you can use java.util.ServiceLoader.

Or you take a look at apache discovery
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-discovery/apidocs/org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/Service.html.

It's more powerful than the java.util.SerivceLoader since it lets you pass constructor arguments the the services it instantiates.

A possible plugin loader implementation could look like:

```
public interface ServiceInterface {

}

public class PluginHost {   

    public ServiceLoader<ServiceInterface> loadPlugins() {
        File[] pluginLibraries = getPluginLibraries();
        URL[] pluginLibUrls = new URL[pluginLibraries.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pluginLibUrls.length; i++) {
            try {
                pluginLibUrls[i] = pluginLibraries[i].toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to load plugin: "
                        + pluginLibraries[i], e);
            }
        }

        URLClassLoader pluginsClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(pluginLibUrls,
                ServiceInterface.class.getClassLoader());

        ServiceLoader<ServiceInterface> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(
                ServiceInterface.class, pluginsClassLoader);

        return serviceLoader;
    }

    private File[] getPluginLibraries() {
        // please implement
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one last question, what if I wanted to put the jar files somewhere else? As in not in the classpath that it's running from.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

Jars are just zipped class files.

As long as the class files are in the classpath you're fine.

---

Unzip a jar file (rename from .jar to .zip and unzip) to see what the directory structure should be for the java packages.

Comment: do you know of any examples I could look at possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can load a class at runtime and create a Class object also:

See this [`Class#forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29):

See [**this tutorial for examples**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple extension mechanism have a look at [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

For a more complete extension mechanism have a look at OSGi.